# How to do many to many join in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have these tables in oracle

TABLE A

```
ID GROUP NUMBER1
1   CAT1    0.4
2   CAT2    0.5
```

TABLE  B

```
ID VALUE1   VALUE2
1   5           9
1   6          10
2   7          11
2   8          12
```

TABLE C

```
ID NUM1   NUM2
1   13     17
1   14     18
2   15     19
2   16     20
```

How can I join all three tables so that I get out put that looks like this?

```
ID  GRUP    NUMBER1   VALUE1  VALUE2  NUM1  NUM2
1    CAT1      0.4        5       9     13    17
1    CAT1      0.4        6      10     14    18
2    CAT2      0.5        7      11     15    19
2    CAT2      0.5        8      12     16    20
```

Currently I do

```
select group, number1, value1, value2, num2, num2
 from tablea a inner join tableb b inner join a.id = b.id
inner join tablec inner join c.id = a.id
```

and I am getting many duplicate rows.

When I join Table A to Table B I get 6 rows. That is good. I inner join those tables on ID.

Now I just want to still have 6 rows but I want to bring in the columns in TABLE C num1 and num2 by JOINING on ID again.  So I'd like to have 6 rows all joined by ID that with the columns in the out put.

Comment: By what logic do you pair (5,9) from one table with (13, 17) from another, and separately you pair (6, 10) with (14, 18)? Why not (5,9) paired with (14, 18) and (6, 10) with (13, 17)? It is impossible to write code to solve a problem, if the problem itself is not clearly defined (which means, **in plain English**, with no use of any code whatsoever).

Comment: *many to many* by definition means you will get *many multiple rows*. In addition, there is no correlation between the data you've provided and the output you're asking to obtain. You're going to need to clearly explain *in precise terms* how you expect the data to get from the individual tables to what you're asking to get as a result. When explaining, remember we know *absolutely nothing* about what you're trying to do other than what you say in your post; we can't read your mind to figure out what you're trying to do. So **be specific and clear** about how you expect to get the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> " i am getting many duplicate rows"

This is because you have no defined 1:1 relationship between the rows in table `B`and table `C`. So your query generates a cross join.

One option is to fake an identifier using an analytic function like `row_number()`.

```
select a.group, a.number1, b.value1, b.value2, c.num2, c.num2
from tablea a 
     inner join ( select id, value1, value2 
                         , row_number() over (partition by id order by value1) rn
                  from tableb  ) b
                on a.id = b.id
     inner join ( select id, num1, num2 
                         , row_number() over (partition by id order by num1) rn
                  from tablec ) c 
            on a.id = c.id
where b.rn = c.rn
/
```

This will work as long as you have the same number of rows per ID in `B` and `C`. (If that's true there's probably some problem with your data model, but that's a different matter.)